# How to count missing values/rows as 0 when calculating an average?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table similar to the one below:

| Player | Round | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 4 |
| A | 2 | 4 |
| A | 3 | 5 |
| A | 4 | 4 |
| B | 3 | 5 |
| B | 4 | 6 |

I want to calculate the average points scored by both players combined for each round with a sql query like this:

```
select round, avg(points) as avg_points
from results
group by round
order by round;
```

But I want the rounds that player B didn't participate in to count as 0 for player b.
So **avg_points for round 1 should return 2 instead of 4** (as it does right now with my query).

Please note: Solutions needs to work with an arbitrary number of players and rounds they have participated in.

(The database I use is Exasol, problem was also replicated in MySQL.)

*Edit: Deleted the part about what I have already tried and shortened the question alltogether, as the additional information seemed to be confusing and distracted people from my main problem...*

Comment: Why not just `SELECT round, (SUM(points) / 2) AS avg_points FROM results GROUP BY round ORDER BY round`?

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the desired result.

Comment: The join is fine. The problem is `and r.player = 'A' or r.player = 'B'` Change that to `and (r.player = 'A' or r.player = 'B')` or `and r.player IN ('A', 'B')`